# HTML5 getCurrentPosition on PhoneGap going to error handler with weird null error, on Android only

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application which immediately sets window.location to be my on-internet site and carries on working from there. The app works great except for the following very strange behaviour.

I'm trying to get a geolocation by calling:

```
function geoErrorHandler(error) {
    console.log("getCurrentPosition failed with error message: " + error.message);
}
function showPosition(position) {
// blah
}

var options = {maximumAge:60000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, geoErrorHander, options);
```

On iOS it works fine in my PhoneGap app. It also works fine when the page is just loaded in a desktop browser. On my Android PhoneGap app, however, it calls my geoErrorHandler. Which is fine - surely I can find out then what the problem was! Except it calls it with an error which has error.message = "" and error.code = null. Hrhum.

It's doing this on two separate devices and a fair amount of internet searching doesn't seem to reveal anyone else with this behaviour. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: are you waiting for `deviceready` event to fire before calling this?

Comment: I am, yes. I've cut down the code a little.

Comment: @ChrisR Can you try the same `geolocation()` function without switching `window.location` to  your internet site?. Just to rule out that the switching to your internet site is not causing the issue.

Comment: For those interested in this... I created a new project from scratch and it seems not to be happening any more. So, somehow, I'm thinking perhaps the wrong version of Cordova was being loaded or something weird.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a permission problem?

Try adding to your manifest ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Thanks for looking - PhoneGap Build manages the manifest- once I've added <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" /> to its config.xml, it adds the permissions ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to its generated manifest. It doesn't add ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS but (given that nobody else seems to have this exact problem) I'm not sure that's going to the root of it. :(